# What does the word "אש" in Vayikra 1:7 refer to?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, words, fire-burning, parashat-vayikra

אש is generally translated as "fire."  However, consider [Vayikra 1:7](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9902#v=7):

> וְנָתְנוּ בְּנֵי אַהֲרֹן הַכֹּהֵן אֵשׁ עַל הַמִּזְבֵּחַ וְעָרְכוּ עֵצִים עַל הָאֵשׁ
>
> The sons of Aharon the Kohen shall put "אש" onto the altar, and they shall arrange wood on top of the "אש"

"Fire" doesn't seem to make sense in this context - the wood would come before the fire.  Can אש have a broader meaning which is not just "fire"?

I realize that Rashi's comment here does seem to imply that it refers to fire. I'm not sure what the fire is being caught on to.  According to Rashi, is there something else not mentioned in the verse that is already on the altar to which the fire is catching?

Comment: It was a starter fire, a kindling. Much like in parshas Vayeira 22 6. You put the wood on top of it to get the real fire going.

Comment: @user6591 so it was a burning object, not just flames.  I'm used to אש meaning flames, i.e. the fire itself.  (As much as that seems to be the obvious direction of the verse, can you support that claim?)

Comment: Just from Vayera where the item called eish was being held in someone's hand. Otherwise ouch!

Comment: @user6591 You _are_ talking about someone who was thrown into a fiery furnace and came out okay :)

Comment: well played sir.

Comment: I thought that it means the following - They start a fire (I assume that there was already wood in the base of the alter. Then it says to arrange wood on the fire, i.e. - similar to a grid on a barbeque. This wood goes on the top of the fire so that they can place the sacrificial meat on top of these pieces of wood. Is that a correct explanation?

Comment: @DanF I don't know if it is correct, but I would want an explanation of why the Torah only saw fit to fill us in about one layer of wood.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Talmud ([Yoma 45a](https://www.sefaria.org/Yoma.45a.12?lang=bi)) quotes a [*baraita*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baraita) as interpreting this "placing of fire" to mean starting the fire by kindling little wood chips<sup>1</sup>:

> רבי יוסי הצתת אליתא מנא ליה נפקא ליה מהיכא דנפקא ליה לרבי שמעון דתניא (ויקרא א, ז) ונתנו בני אהרן הכהן אש על המזבח לימד על הצתת אליתא שלא תהא אלא בכהן כשר ובכלי שרת דברי ר' יהודה אמר לו רבי שמעון וכי תעלה על דעתך שזר קרב לגבי מזבח אלא לימד על הצתת אליתא שלא תהא אלא בראשו של מזבח
>
> And from where does Rabbi Yosei derive that the kindling of the wood chips should be at the top of the altar? He derives it from the same place that Rabbi Shimon derives it. As it was taught in a baraita: The verse states: “And the sons of Aaron the priest shall put fire upon the altar” (Leviticus 1:7), which teaches about the kindling of the wood chips that it may be done only by a fit priest and one who is robed in the priestly vestments of service; this is the statement of Rabbi Yehuda. Rabbi Shimon said to him: There is no need for a verse to teach that a priest must kindle the chips, for could it enter your mind that a non-priest could approach the altar? Rather, this verse teaches about the kindling of the wood chips, that they may be lit only at the top of the altar. <sup>2</sup>

---

<sup>1. As [user6591](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/6591/user6591) suggested in a comment on the question.</sup>
<sup>2. English from The William Davidson digital edition of the Koren Noé Talmud, with commentary by Rabbi Adin Steinsaltz Even-Israel. Used with permission under the [CC-BY-NC](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc/4.0/) license.</sup>